# UWP App Crashes on Resuming After Being Idle for a While

Tags: uwp

I am developing my UWP music player app for years. I've encountered an issue where the app **crashes when it resumes after being idle for an uncertain period of time**. However, if the music player keeps playing, the app functions perfectly fine. The crash occurs when the app is brought back into focus after being idle. I cannot steadily reproduce the crash, but it does come most of the time. I just don't know how long it takes.

I have attempted to diagnose the issue by attaching a debugger, but the crash doesn't occur when the debugger is attached. In the `class App : Application`, I have added try-catchs and logs to the `Resuming`, `Suspending` and `UnhandledException` method, but still couldn't pinpoint the cause of the crash.

I'm at a loss on how to further troubleshoot this problem. Any suggestions on what steps to take next or how to properly **diagnose and avoid such crash** would be greatly appreciated.

This is partially the code of my music player

```
public class MusicPlayer : IMusicEventListener
{
    public static MediaPlaybackState PlaybackState => Player.PlaybackSession.PlaybackState;
    public static bool IsPlaying => PlaybackState == MediaPlaybackState.Playing;
    public static Playlist NowPlaying => new Playlist(MenuFlyoutHelper.NowPlaying, CurrentPlaylist);
    private static MediaPlaybackList PlaybackList = new MediaPlaybackList() { MaxPlayedItemsToKeepOpen = 1 };
    public static MediaPlayer Player = new MediaPlayer() { Source = PlaybackList };
}
```

The is partially the code of my App class

```
sealed partial class App : Application
{
    public static bool Inited { get; private set; } = false;
    public static List<Action> LoadedListeners = new List<Action>();
    public App()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Suspending += OnSuspending;
        this.Resuming += App_Resuming;
        this.UnhandledException += App_UnhandledException;
    }

    private void App_Resuming(object sender, object e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"sender {sender.GetType()} e {e}");
    }

    protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
        OnLaunched(e, null);
    }

    private void OnSuspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
    {
        var deferral = e.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral();
        try
        {
            TileHelper.ResumeTile();
            ToastHelper.HideToast();
            Save();
            SQLHelper.ClearInactive();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Warn($"OnSuspending exception {ex}");
        }
        deferral.Complete();
    }

    public static async void Save()
    {
        SettingsHelper.Save();
        MusicPlayer.Save();
        await Helper.ClearBackups(10);
    }

    protected override void OnBackgroundActivated(BackgroundActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        var deferral = args.TaskInstance.GetDeferral();
        switch (args.TaskInstance.Task.Name)
        {
            case ToastHelper.ToastTaskName:
                if (args.TaskInstance.TriggerDetails is Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationActionTriggerDetail details)
                {
                    // Perform tasks
                    if (Enum.TryParse(typeof(ToastButtonEnum), details.Argument, out object toastButton))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            HandleBackgroundActivation((ToastButtonEnum)toastButton);
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            Log.Warn($"HandleBackgroundActivation failed {e}");
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
        deferral.Complete();
    }

    private async void HandleBackgroundActivation(ToastButtonEnum toastButton)
    {
        switch (toastButton)
        {
            case ToastButtonEnum.Next:
                MusicPlayer.MoveNext();
                if (MusicPlayer.PlayMode == PlayMode.RepeatOne)
                {
                    ToastHelper.HideToast();
                    await ToastHelper.ShowToast(MusicPlayer.CurrentMusic, MusicPlayer.PlaybackState);
                }
                break;
            case ToastButtonEnum.Pause:
                MusicPlayer.Pause();
                break;
            case ToastButtonEnum.Play:
                MusicPlayer.Play();
                break;
            case ToastButtonEnum.SwitchLyricsSourceToMusic:
                await ToastHelper.SwitchLyricsSource(LyricsSource.Music);
                break;
            case ToastButtonEnum.SwitchLyricsSourceToLrcFile:
                await ToastHelper.SwitchLyricsSource(LyricsSource.LrcFile);
                break;
            case ToastButtonEnum.SwitchLyricsSourceToInternet:
                await ToastHelper.SwitchLyricsSource(LyricsSource.Internet);
                break;
        }
    }

    protected override async void OnFileActivated(FileActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        base.OnFileActivated(args);
        Music music = await Music.LoadFromPathAsync(args.Files[0].Path);
        Log.Info("activate file " + args.Files[0].Path);
        if (music == null)
        {
            Helper.ShowButtonedNotification("CannotReadLocalMusicFile", "Authorize", async (n) =>
            {
                await StorageHelper.AuthorizeFolder();
            });
            return;
        }
        if (args.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Running)
        {
            MusicPlayer.AddNextAndPlay(music);
        }
        else
        {
            OnLaunched(null, music);
        }
    }

    private void App_UnhandledException(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        Log.Error("App_UnhandledException {0}", e.Exception);
    }

}
```

Comment: It's hard to locate the issue if this behavior can't be reproduced. I'd suggest you use [App Center](https://appcenter.ms/) to check the crash logs.

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT Thanks, this could be helpful. I am also looking for tools that allows me to log the cause of the crash.

Comment: Vs debugger is the tool that you need if you could reproduce this issue. If you can't reproduce this issue, then you could only check the crash log.

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT I know, but the weird thing is that such crash never comes when a vs debugger is attached QAQ.

Comment: As I've mentioned, you need to check the crash log using App Center.

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT Thank you! I think I located the problem that caused the crash!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An exception was thrown in the `Save()` function, and the function is `async void` not `async Task`. Thus, its exception was thrown asynchronously and not caught in the OnSuspending. So the solution would simply catch the problem in the `Save()` function.

```
private void OnSuspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
{
    var deferral = e.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral();
    try
    {
        TileHelper.ResumeTile();
        ToastHelper.HideToast();
        Save();
        SQLHelper.ClearInactive();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Warn($"OnSuspending exception {ex}");
    }
    deferral.Complete();
}

public static async void Save()
{
    SettingsHelper.Save();
    MusicPlayer.Save();
    await Helper.ClearBackups(10);
}
```